# Android: Time delay in a loop with updating UI

Tags: android, loops, time, delay, progress

What I'm trying to create is a simple progress bar, that would load for ~10 sec.
So what I want is a for loop like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                    progressDialog.setProgress(i);
                    //100ms delay
                }
```

Thanks

Comment: doc: AsyncTask ... do NOT do blocking operation in UI thread !!!

Comment: @Selvin, but maybe it's not AsyncTask

Comment: i just pointed what he **should** use :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code may be helpful for you.

```
public void startProgress(View view) {
    // Do something long
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                final int value = i;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progressDialog.setProgress(value);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Async Task for the purpose

in preExecute() method initialize loop index to 0;

in background process sleep thread for 10 seconds, and then call sendUpdate method to send progress

in postExecute update progress bar to progress get in parameter.

Answer (score 1):

A shorter solution without explicitly creating a new Thread would look like this:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
final int sleepMs = 100;
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) {
    handler.postDelayed(() -> progressDialog.setProgress(value), i * sleepMs);
}
```